# How to check file extension when drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I've done an upload file that can accept multiple files but my current problem is when user drag and drop multiple it accept other doc type file beside than image file.Here's my code for it:

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
           <label class="fieldlabels">Photos:</label> 
              <!--input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"-->
                                        
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_name2"  onchange="return fileValidation2()" name="file_name2" value="" title="Photos" accept="image/*" multiple="true"/>        
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" id="add_files2">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                  <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
                  <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                  <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                  <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Type</th>
                  <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
 </tbody>
/table>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my script that I've done so far:

```
function fileValidation2(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file_name2');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.tiff|\.tif)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Please upload file having extensions .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.tiff/.tif/.xlsx/.pdf/.xls/.docx/.doc/.bump only.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
        //Image preview
        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('imagePreview').innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'"/>';
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working perfectly when user click the choose file in the input file but when user drag and drop multiple that contain files beside than image it's till included.Did anyone know how to slove this ? Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIbb.png

The zip file and other files still included when user drag and drop multiple files.

Comment: you can do at least the "cheap version" and does in your loop again, what you used before  `if(!allowedExtensions.exec(fileInput.files[0].name)){ return; }`

Comment: can you show me how it works ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to override the events `dragover` and `drop`, these events have a `dataTransfer.files` field that is the same interface as the file-input `files`, a `FileList`.

```js
const tbl = document.getElementById('file-table')

function formatSize(n){
  for(const unit of ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']){
    if(n > 1024){
      n /= 1024;
    }else{
      if(n < 10){
        return n.toFixed(2) + unit
      }else{
        return n.toFixed(0) + unit;
      }
    }
  }
}


function fileValidation2(files){
    // Get file input from event target
    
    
    var allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.tiff|\.tif)$/i;
    
    for(const file of files){
      if(!allowedExtensions.exec(file.name)){
          alert('Please upload file having extensions .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.tiff/.tif/.xlsx/.pdf/.xls/.docx/.doc/.bump only.');
          fileInput.value = '';
          return false;
      }else{
          //Image preview
          if (file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(e) {
                  // add one row to the file table
                  const row = tbl.insertRow()
                  // Create preview element
                  const img = document.createElement('img')
                  img.src = e.target.result;
                  img.classList.add('preview') // style 
                  row.insertCell().appendChild(img);
                  
                  row.insertCell().innerText = file.name;
                  // you decide what goes here
                  row.insertCell().innerText = 'pending';
                  // file.size has size in bytes, make it human readable
                  row.insertCell().innerText = formatSize(file.size)
                  // Trick to get file extension take the last item of the
                  // array obtained from the string splitted by dots.
                  row.insertCell().innerText = file.name.split('.').pop()
                  
                  // you decide what goes here
                  row.insertCell().innerText = '??'
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
      }
    }
}

const row = tbl.insertRow();
const cell = row.insertCell()

document.getElementById('file_name2')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => fileValidation2(e.target.files))

document.body.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  if(e.dataTransfer.files){
    // here you can get information from the files
    // even before dropping them
    document.body.classList.add('files')
  }
})

document.body.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  document.body.classList.remove('files');
})

document.body.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
  if(e.dataTransfer.files){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()   
    fileValidation2(e.dataTransfer.files);
    document.body.classList.remove('files')
  }
})
```

```css
#file-table th {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

img.preview {
  max-width: 4e;
  max-height: 4em;
}

body.files {
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
  border: 3mm solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
           <label class="fieldlabels">Photos:</label> 
              <!--input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"-->
                                        
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_name2" name="file_name2" value="" title="Photos" accept="image/*" multiple="true"/>          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" id="file-table">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                  <th>Preview</th>
                  <th>File Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>File Size</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. The dragover event will not expose any dragged files. The items property will contain a file type entry (no useful data like name, size, etc). The drop event exposes files and items as stated in this answer.

Comment: Maybe different environments will have different behaviors. In my case, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.7` it works fine.